# Angular CLI budget for lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using the `budgets` option introduced in Angular CLI 1.7 version. I'm generating my bundles with `ng build -prod --named-chunks`

Everything is working fine for setting up budgets for the default bundles (`main`, `polyfills`, etc). But I cannot find a way to set a budget for my own lazy loaded module.

[image]

```
  "budgets": [
    { "type": "bundle", "name": "common", "baseline": "50kb", "warning": "25kb" },
    { "type": "bundle", "name": "inline", "baseline": "50kb", "warning": "25kb" },
    { "type": "bundle", "name": "polyfills", "baseline": "50kb", "warning": "25kb" },
    { "type": "bundle", "name": "styles", "baseline": "50kb", "warning": "25kb" },
    { "type": "bundle", "name": "main", "baseline": "500kb", "warning": "200kb" },
    // this doesn't work
    { "type": "bundle", "name": "summary.module", "baseline": "200kb", "warning": "100kb" },
    // this doesn't work
    { "type": "bundle", "name": "summary", "baseline": "200kb", "warning": "100kb" }
  ]
```

I'm not interedted in using `type: "anyScript"` or `type: "any"`, because the main bundle will almost always be larger than any lazy loaded module, and I would have to set the target way to large, to not trigger the warning for my `main` bundle.

Comment: Did you get budgets to work for lazy loaded modules? I'm still facing this problem even after trying all different suggestions for naming. However, there is an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11019) regarding this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For named chunks, you have to use a syntax like `<module_name>-src-lib-<module_name>-module-ngfactory` (based on angular 6).